# Cannot infer arguments for reversed Comparator in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, comparator

Just when I think I am a super-expert in Java generics, a simple thing throws me for a loop. I'm using Java 8 in Eclipse 4.6.3.

Let's say I make an enum of orderings for `FooBar`, and I want each enum value to give me a `Comparator<? extends FooBar>` appropriate for the ordering:

```
public enum FooBarOrdering {
  BY_FOO_ASCENDING, BY_FOO_DESCENDING;

  public Comparator<? extends FooBar> getComparator() {
    switch (this) {
      case BY_FOO_ASCENDING:
        return Comparator.comparing(fooBar -> fooBar.getFoo());
      //…
    }
  }
}
```

Yay, that works for a charm, just like I thought it would! (Yes, here I could use a method reference, but ignore that for now ---that's irrelevant to the issue here.) Now to add the comparator for `BY_FOO_DESCENDING`.

Hmmm... first of all, Eclipse's auto-complete doesn't seem to work on the returned comparator. Never mind --- I know how to read Javadocs, so I add this:

```
case BY_FOO_DESCENDING:
  return Comparator.comparing(fooBar -> fooBar.getFoo()).reversed();
```

Eclipse now tells me: `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <T, U> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U>)`

And also: `The method getFoo() is undefined for the type Object`

Now why did `getFoo()` work just fine in the first example, but did not work when I call *a method from the returned Comparator value*? If Eclipse/Java knew that there was a `FooBar` with a `getFoo()` method in the earlier code, why did adding a `reversed()` method on the return value change anything?

And here's how silly it gets: look at the source code for `Comparator.reversed())`; it simply returns `Collections.reverseOrder(this)`. So if I change the code to the following, it works fine:

```
case BY_FOO_DESCENDING:
  return Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(fooBar -> fooBar.getFoo()));
```

So is this an Eclipse bug? Or is Java still just a bit dumb when it comes to generics? Or am I missing something?

I would really like to use `Comparator.reversed()`, so if you tell me some cast or `<blah>` I can add to the expression to make it work, that would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Try `Comparator<? extends FooBar> c = Comparator.comparing(fooBar -> fooBar.getFoo()); return c.reversed();`

Comment: Or `Comparator.comparing(fooBar -> fooBar.getFoo(), Comparator.reverseOrder())`

Comment: Also it looks the same with intellij

Comment: It's not generics, it's Lambda. Check this: `Comparator<FooBar> reversed= Comparator.comparing(new Function<FooBar, Integer>() { @Override public Integer apply(FooBar t) { return 0; } }).reversed();` (use code formatter) I already fought similar battles :-/